# Php header 301 redirect still let google to index content but now from my redirected domain

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-status-code-301

I've redirect my oldsite.tld site via PHP header like this.

```
<?php 
$url_sufix = "blabla";
header("Location: http://www.newsite.tld/".$url_sufix, true, 301);
exit;
```

After 3 mo I still can find fresh indexed content on google for oldsite.tld, with content and url_sufix from newsite.tld
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en

Comment: But why 301 redirect don't work like it should to be?

Comment: How are you finding this fresh content?  Are you looking in Google Search Console, or are you trying to rely on a `site:` search?

Comment: Your code is doing what it is supposed to.  This isn't a programming question.  This is a question about why Google is reacting in a certain way.  This type of question would be better asked at [webmasters.se].

Comment: I'm not sure my code is doing it is supposed to, because with `site:` and checking a date of cached content shows me that content is fresh from newly redirected site. This is something which should not happen. I'm loosing my positions because double content. ~200k indexed pages is affected.. Firs I was thinking that I have wrong outdated code, but now not sure.